# Group multiple RadioButton lists

Tags: html, asp.net, controls, radiobuttonlist

I have several Radio Button lists on my page, each lists items under different categories, so they are listed under different headings.

I only want one item to be selected across all the lists however.

Is it possible to "group" the lists so that the affectively behave as one RadioButton Lists?

I want to avoid using jQuery/Javascript if possible

Comment: RadioButtonList, Itself represent Group.. You take radiobutton and set category wise by using html and design thing.

Answer (score 1):

Not using the standard ASP.Net radio button list control I believe. The best thing to do would be to render out your radio buttons one-by-one in their individual lists and of course, set the "name" property so they all belong to the same group.

You could also (depending on the structure of your data) just render all options in one radio button list control and then use the css nth child selectors to insert divs/line breaks/etc. But you would probably need jQuery for this unless your targeting only browsers that supports CSS3.